# Site doesn't display styling on Firefox or IE –– works fine with Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox

I'm using the Blaszok Wordpress theme and my styling isn't in showing up in Firefox or IE. The site works fine in Chrome and Safari.

Site: http://completetrackandfield.com/

It displays the header twice and shows plain text links without styling.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Some code please? Check to see if the code for linking the external css file is correct. Do some testing for inline styles and more.

Comment: @www139 This is the link from header.php that references the stylesheet. What other code would you like to look at that would be helpful?

<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('http://test.completetrackandfield.com/wp-content/themes/blaszok/style.css'); ?>" />

Comment: Is that all the code for header.php? Also please post the code in your question

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if your problem has to do with a same-origin policy violation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Basically, your website is completetrackandfield.com and the CSS file attempting to load is served from www.test.completetrackandfield.com -- Firefox (and I believe IE) block these requests because cross-domain requests like this can be used in Cross-site Request forgery attacks.

More to the point, I'm not sure why the theme is calling bloginfo('test.completetrackandfield.com...'); in that way. Instead, you should be using:

```
<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>
```

inside the href="". Give that a shot and let us know if that fixes things for you.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. I was going to ask that he put all this files on the same server and test again.

Comment: @Josh Breedon - Any updates on this? Did you fix the issue based on the above info?